# Transform quotes to angle quotes using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, quotes

I am searching for a way to automatically transform quotes in a XML file to angle quotes using XSL.

Example XML:

```
<root>
  <p>There "are" quotes</p>
  <p>Here "are quotes <b>too</b>"</p>
</root>
```

This should be transformed to:

```
<root>
  <p>There »are« quotes</p>
  <p>Here »are quotes <b>too</b>«</p>
</root>
```

Is this possible in XSL? Please also not that the starting quote doesn't need to be in the same tag as the ending quote.

Comment: Is there a limit of how far back you want to look, or do you just want to replace every odd quote **in the entire document** with `»` and every even one with `«`? Note that any way you choose to look at this, you will be tripped by `"Yes, we have 5" nails", he said.`

Comment: In theory there is no limit. In a real document the start and end quote will probably be within some tag (not in a text-node which is a direct child of that tag but somewhere within the tag). The 3rd quote would cause an error but that would be a problem for the data generation.

Comment: Please tell us what XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: At the moment i am using Xalan 2.7.1. But that is something i could change if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For continuous strings/text nodes, this recursive function works:

```
<xsl:template name="quote">
  <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
  <xsl:param name="old" select="'&quot;&quot;'" />
  <xsl:param name="new" select="'»«'" />
  <xsl:param name="state" select="0" />

  <xsl:variable name="o" select="substring($old, $state + 1, 1)" />
  <xsl:variable name="n" select="substring($new, $state + 1, 1)" />

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($o and contains($text, $o))">
      <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $o)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$n" /> 
      <xsl:call-template name="quote">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $o)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="old" select="$old" />
        <xsl:with-param name="new" select="$new" />
        <xsl:with-param name="state" select="($state + 1) mod 2" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

If you supply the `$old` and `$new` parameters, they should be be strings of length 2, containing characters for the opening and closing quotes, respectively.

Exemple that uses default values for all parameters:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="quote" />
</xsl:template>
```

---

If the text nodes in question are part of a nested structure (`<p>Here "are quotes <b>too</b>"</p>`) things are a little more complicated.

To achieve asymmetric quoting (different opening and closing quotes) across non-continuous text nodes, we need to make a few assumptions:

- We are going to use quote-counting, i.e. if a quote is preceded by an even number of quotes (0, 2, 4 ...), we assume it to be an opening quote, otherwise we assume a closing quote.
- We are going to assume all relevant quoting happens on the sibling level (no "incorrect nesting", such as `text "text <x>"</x>`, where the closing quote is on a different nesting level).
- Quotes need to be correct in the input or our counting will be off.
- For maximum compatibility I am going to assume an vanilla XSLT 1.0 processor.

First we need a function that can count characters in an input text. We are going to use it as the base of our quote counting approach. This is easy enough; as a small complication we design it to be able to count multiple different characters:

```
<xsl:template name="count-chars">
  <xsl:param name="input" select="." />
  <xsl:param name="chars" select="$input" />

  <xsl:value-of select="
    string-length($input) - string-length(translate($input, $chars, ''))
  " />
</xsl:template>
```

When called with `$input = "input A input B"` and `$chars = "AB"` it would return 2. Called without any arguments it would simply return the overall string length of the input (which defaults to the current node).

Next we need a template that is able to count characters across a set of nodes. This works basically by iterating the input set of nodes and calling `count-chars` on every one of them. Again this is recursive to be able to calculate a grand total:

```
<xsl:template name="count-chars-mutiple">
  <xsl:param name="nodes" />
  <xsl:param name="chars" />

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($chars and count($nodes))">
      <xsl:value-of select="0" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="c">
        <xsl:call-template name="count-chars">
          <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$nodes[1]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="chars" select="$chars" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="d">
        <xsl:call-template name="count-chars-mutiple">
          <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() &gt; 1]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="chars" select="$chars" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$c + $d" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This is pretty straight-forward.

When called with `$nodes = ["input A input B", "input A input C"]` and  and `$chars = "AB"` it would return 3.

With the support functions set up, we can now modifiy the function from the start of my post to be able to get its context from quote counting.

For this we are going to count the quotes across all preceding-sibling text nodes and base our decision which quote to use on that count plus the count of quotes in the text node at hand.

So for example:

```
<p>Here "<i>are</i> quotes <b>too</b>", and "here"</p>
   -----^          --------          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        1                            2      3    4
```

When we are at the text last text node (~) the underlined text nodes are taken into consideration, the first of which contains one quote (1), so we know quote (2) is a closing quote. (3) and (4) are treated just like in my original function (i.e. through recursion):

```
  <xsl:template name="quote">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
    <xsl:param name="old" select="'&quot;&quot;'" />
    <xsl:param name="new" select="'»«'" />
    <xsl:param name="context">
      <xsl:call-template name="count-chars-mutiple">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="preceding-sibling::text()" />
        <xsl:with-param name="chars" select="$old" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="state" select="($context mod 2) + 1" />
    <xsl:variable name="o" select="substring($old, $state, 1)" />
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="substring($new, $state, 1)" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($o and contains($text, $o))">
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $o)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$n" />
        <xsl:call-template name="quote">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $o)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="old" select="$old" />
          <xsl:with-param name="new" select="$new" />
          <xsl:with-param name="context" select="$context + 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

`$state` ends up being either 1 or 2 so we can choose either the opening or closing quote from the `$new` parameter. `$context` defaults to the respective preceding quote count and is simply incremented for the next recursive step.

I know this isn't exactly pretty, but when put together it transforms your input into this:

```
<root>
  <p>There »are« quotes</p>
  <p>Here »are quotes <b>too</b>«</p>
</root>
```

```html
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:call-template name="quote" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="quote">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
    <xsl:param name="old" select="'&quot;&quot;'" />
    <xsl:param name="new" select="'»«'" />
    <xsl:param name="context">
      <xsl:call-template name="count-chars-mutiple">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="preceding-sibling::text()" />
        <xsl:with-param name="chars" select="$old" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="state" select="($context mod 2) + 1" />
    <xsl:variable name="o" select="substring($old, $state, 1)" />
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="substring($new, $state, 1)" />
    
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($o and contains($text, $o))">
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $o)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$n" />
        <xsl:call-template name="quote">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $o)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="old" select="$old" />
          <xsl:with-param name="new" select="$new" />
          <xsl:with-param name="context" select="$context + 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="count-chars">
    <xsl:param name="input" select="." />
    <xsl:param name="chars" select="$input" />
  
    <xsl:value-of select="
      string-length($input) - string-length(translate($input, $chars, ''))
    " />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="count-chars-mutiple">
    <xsl:param name="nodes" />
    <xsl:param name="chars" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($chars and count($nodes))">
        <xsl:value-of select="0" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="c">
          <xsl:call-template name="count-chars">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$nodes[1]" />
            <xsl:with-param name="chars" select="$chars" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="d">
          <xsl:call-template name="count-chars-mutiple">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() &gt; 1]" />
            <xsl:with-param name="chars" select="$chars" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$c + $d" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:transform>
```

Side note: `<xsl:param>` allows references to the values of params declared earlier in the same function, so that parameters can calculate their own default values dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but sadly the "more complicated" case is needed for me. So it would probably make sense not doing this using XSL but some programming language?

Comment: I'm working on the "more complicated" case. Give me a minute.

Comment: Great. Please take my comment in the initial question into consideration. The start and end quote will be within some kind of tag (not direct children but somewhere within). Maybe this could help :)

Comment: @Werzi2001 There you go, vanilla XSLT 1.0 solution, compatible with whatever you use. Since your XSLT processor supports [the EXSLT extensions](http://exslt.org/exsl/) I bet you can find ways of making this more efficient and less verbose. But for now, it works.

Comment: Good solution. Unfortunately works only in limited cases -- see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do something like Text-Processors do to set typographic correct quotes: If there is a character following, we have the opening quote. If a character preceeds, we have a closing one.

In the following XSLT, I show a solution where I'm just looking for white-space before or after the quote. It's not a solution for all cases (think of punctuation or something like that) and it does not match all cases one can think of, but it may help for your use case - at least your example is print out well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>

    <!-- the easy ones: -->
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="replace($this,'&quot;([^\s])','»$1')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="replace($this,'([^\s])&quot;','$1«')"/>

    <!-- now, try handling &quot; at the beginning/end of text() -->
    <xsl:variable name="this">  
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="matches($this,'^&quot;') and matches(preceding-sibling::*[1]/text(),'[^\s]$')">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace($this,'^&quot;','«')"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="matches($this,'&quot;$') and matches(following-sibling::*[1]/text(),'^[^\s]')">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace($this,'^&quot;','»')"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$this"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:value-of select="$this"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: *"If there is a character following, we have the opening quote. If a character preceeds, we have a closing one."* - except in situations like this one: `("we are in parens")` or a thousand other configurations.

Comment: Yes, of course! I tried to show the principle of my idea: you can easily add parenthesis, punctuation and so on to the regexes. The problem isn't easy and I think you only can get close to the perfect solution, you won't ever reach it.

Comment: True. The solution I'm currently working on makes assumptions of its own and isn't very pretty, either. :|

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**:

**Here is a transformation** that has 20% less templates (4 vs. 5) than the (very good) solution by Tomalak, and 19% less code (68 (or 63 in Sol.2) vs. 81 lines). No `<xsl:choose>`, `<xsl:when>`, `<xsl:otherwise>` or `translate()` are used. The maximum number of parameters for any template is 3, and in Solution 2 this maximum number of parameters is 2 (vs.4). To put it simple, **I believe these 2 transformations are simpler**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vQ">"</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="vShevrons" select="'»«'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vReplacedText">
   <xsl:call-template name="replQuotes"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vNodeOffsets">
   <xsl:call-template name="getTextOffsets"/>
   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replQuotes">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="pOddness" select="0"/>

    <xsl:value-of select='substring-before(concat($pText, $vQ), $vQ)'/>

    <xsl:variable name="vRemaining" select="substring-after($pText, $vQ)"/>

    <xsl:if test="contains($pText, $vQ)">
      <xsl:variable name="vShevInd" select="$pOddness + 1"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($vShevrons, $vShevInd, 1)"/>

      <xsl:call-template name="replQuotes">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$vRemaining"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pOddness" select="$vShevInd mod 2"/> 
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[true()]">
    <xsl:variable name="vInd" select="count(preceding::text()) +1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vStartMarker" select="concat('|N', $vInd, '|')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vOffset" select="substring-before(substring-after($vNodeOffsets, $vStartMarker), '|')"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="substring($vReplacedText, $vOffset, string-length())"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getTextOffsets">
    <xsl:param name="pNodes" select="//text()"/>
    <xsl:param name="pNodeInd" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="pAccumLength" select="0"/>

    <xsl:if test="$pNodes">
        <xsl:variable name="vNodeLength" select="string-length($pNodes[1])"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('|N', $pNodeInd, '|')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vNewAccum" select="$pAccumLength+$vNodeLength"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$pAccumLength+1"/>

        <xsl:call-template name="getTextOffsets">
          <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position() > 1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pNodeInd" select="$pNodeInd+1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pAccumLength" select="$vNewAccum"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the originally-provided source XML document**:

```
<root>
  <p>There "are" quotes</p>
  <p>Here "are quotes <b>too</b>"</p>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <p>There »are« quotes</p>
   <p>Here »are quotes <b>too</b>«</p>
</root>
```

**Solution 2**:
In case the XSLT 1.0 processor that is used implements an `xxx:node-set()` extension function, then an even simpler and shorter solution exists:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vQ">"</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="vShevrons" select="'»«'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vReplacedText">
   <xsl:call-template name="replQuotes"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfChunks">
   <xsl:call-template name="getTextChunks"/>
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replQuotes">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="pOddness" select="0"/>

    <xsl:value-of select='substring-before(concat($pText, $vQ), $vQ)'/>

    <xsl:variable name="vRemaining" select="substring-after($pText, $vQ)"/>

    <xsl:if test="contains($pText, $vQ)">
      <xsl:variable name="vShevInd" select="$pOddness + 1"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($vShevrons, $vShevInd, 1)"/>

      <xsl:call-template name="replQuotes">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$vRemaining"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pOddness" select="$vShevInd mod 2"/> 
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[true()]">
    <xsl:variable name="vInd" select="count(preceding::text()) +1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($vrtfChunks)/*[position()=$vInd]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getTextChunks">
    <xsl:param name="pNodes" select="//text()"/>
    <xsl:param name="pTextOffset" select="1"/>

    <xsl:if test="$pNodes">
        <xsl:variable name="vNodeLength" select="string-length($pNodes[1])"/>
      <chunk>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($vReplacedText, $pTextOffset, $vNodeLength)"/>
      </chunk>

      <xsl:call-template name="getTextChunks">
        <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position() > 1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pTextOffset" select="$pTextOffset + $vNodeLength"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Important Note**:  Both these solutions produce correct results if the text nodes of the document are not all siblings. Do note, that Tomalak's transformation doesn't produce correct result in this case.

**Let's take this source XML document**:

```
<root>
  <p>There "are" quotes</p>
  <p>Here "are quotes <b>too " "yes?</b>"</p>
</root>
```

**Both Solution 1 and Solution 2 above produce the correct result**:

```
<root>
   <p>There »are« quotes</p>
   <p>Here »are quotes <b>too « »yes?</b>«</p>
</root>
```

**The transformation from the answer of Tomalak, produces this incorrect result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>

   <p>There »are« quotes</p>

   <p>Here »are quotes <b>too » «yes?</b>«</p>

</root>
```

Comment: I'm going to spend some time analyzing this. Note that the "sibling level" restriction in my solution was deliberate. I wanted some way to restrict the scope of the quote count, sibling level was the easiest, other scopes would have been possible. Also I'm not sure why avoiding `<xsl:choose>, <xsl:when>, <xsl:otherwise>` is an advantage. One can save a few lines of code this way, but XSLT isn't fit for code golf anyway, so line-counting is purely academic.

Comment: @Tomalak, The DRY principle advocates avoiding conditional instructions as much as possible. They increase the complexity of code and make it more difficult to understand, read and maintain. You can read more about avoiding/eliminating XSLT conditional instructions in my Pluralsight course on XSLT 2.0 and 1.0